# Should I talk about "pixels" when talking about the size of views in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, macos

Actually, iPhone OS has an resolution independent measurement for view sizes. It's not really pixels, isn't it? For example, I could make a view 10.55f width, which is blended into fractional pixels then.

But what's the name of that "unit" actually. Can we talk about "Units"? Or is that too generic or even wrong? Can we talk about "Unit Squares"? How would you refer to this in an blog or magazine article?

Same thing seems to apply on MAC OSX as well, I think.

Comment: Ole's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, pixels is not the right word. Apple calls them "points".